# Firefox plugin for tampering browser type

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons

I used to have this firefox plugin that allows me to tamper the request such that it tricks the server thinking that the request comes from iPhone or etc etc.

Certain sites have detection to show different versions of the site depending on what browser is being used, and I would like to do that.

Does anyone knows the plugin name? Can't seem to find it now.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: What is your programming related need for this?

Answer (score 13):

UserAgent Switcher is what you are after:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59

Answer (score 0):

Just use K Meleon
It have inbuilt System for that.
More ever It don't suck processing like firefox

Answer (score 0):

User Agent switcher. Seth mentions one, but if you search for user agent, there have been many addons over the life of firefox to do that. Currently, i think only the one Seth linked you to works.